# Better ways to scraping table on casperjs using casper.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, casperjs

I was trying to scraping down a html(that only use table without ID as structure> and tryig to get each value on  but failed, i have to use findAll function but it seam getting a null.

below is the table data i get in 2nd layer.

```
<tbody><tr bgcolor="#FFCC66" valign="top">
<td><b>No</b></td>
<td><b><a href="search.php?></a></font></b></td>
<td><b><a href="search.php?>Prize</a></font></b></td>
<td>.....
<tr/>
<tbody/>
```

Below was the code i was trying to applied in `casper.evaluate()` but it was return `null` but not the data i needed.

```
var verbs = casper.evaluate(function () {
                    //First layer to peal off all table and added in map to get which table i wanna to.
                    var map = [].map.call(__utils__.findAll('table table'), function (e) { return e.innerHTML; });
                    //map[12] is the table contain multiple tr where i wish to get the value out of td between each tr.
                    var data = map[12];
                    // var newdata = '<html>\n<table>\n'+data+'\n</table>\n</html>';
                    var mapout = [].map.data(__utils__.findAll('tbody tr'), function (e) { return e.innerHTML; });
                    return mapout;
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all rows (and i guess so) this should be an easier way to get it:

```
var rows = casper.evaluate(function() {
  return document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr");
});
```

Afterwards you can iterate throught all rows.

Comment: i guess this will do... but if someone have a better idea will be great